# Check file exist before tar

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I want to tar files based on the date in filename , but if the file didnt exists, tar create a empty tar files

I have files with anychar_20180322_anychar

```
anychar_20180322_anychar.txt
anychar_20180322_anychar.txt
anychar_20180322_anychar.txt
anychar_20180322_anychar.txt
```

I want to tar those files , but before that i want to check files exist in the directory.

example-In the below example there is no file for 20180319 . but you can see a tar file in it .

```
tar: /tmp/dir/*20180319*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous erro
```

rs

```
   -rw------- 1 user group 16M Apr  3 05:31 20180322.tar.gz
  -rw------- 1 user group  45 Apr  3 05:31 20180319.tar.gz
```

code below :

```
d=$(date -d"10 days ago" +%s)
    dt="$(date -d@$((d - i * 86400)) +%Y%m%d)"
    if [ "$dt" -lt "$d" ] && [ test -f "*$dt*" ]; then
    tar czf $fn *$dt*
    fi 
    done
```

how to check atleast one file exist in the particular date and proceed to tar else proceed to another date.

Comment: my normal way of dealing with this is to use a loop (I don't normally use tar like this though...) `for f in *something*; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then echo do stuff here; else exit; fi; done`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to check if a file exists before take an action in shell scripts:

```
# Test file
if [ -f /path/to/file/$FILENAME ]; then
  # do something
else
  echo "file not found"
fi
```

Comment: I want to check multiple files *20180120* . Specific filename didnt work . and not working . Have already tried this method earlier .

Comment: You can try this: 
`for name in *file*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        printf 'at least one file exists (%s)\n' "$name"
        break
    fi
done`

Found this solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417691/how-to-check-if-file-exist-based-on-file-partial-name)

Answer (score 0):

`if [ "$dt" -lt "$d" ] && [ test -f "*$dt*" ]...`

`test` or `[]` but not both
for expansion, no double-quote width
it should be better:

```
if [ "$dt" -lt "$d" ] && [ -f *"$dt"* ]; then
...
```

Comment: Sorry Mate,Not working .test.sh: line 53: [: -f: binary operator expected

Comment: `[ -f repo* ] && echo exists || echo KO`   

=> exists, there is a file repo of course

Comment: `[ test -f repo* ] && echo exists || echo KO` => bash: [: -f : binary operator expected , KO .  you still need to have `[ test -f`, that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
d=$(date -d"10 days ago" +%s)
dt="$(date -d@$((d - i * 86400)) +%Y%m%d)"
if [ "$dt" -lt "$d" ]; then
     for f in *"$dt"*; do # Iterate through everything the glob expands to
         if ! [ -f "$f" ]; then # check whether it exists - if glob finds nothing, the glob itself is returned
            exist=0
         else
            exist=1
         fi
         break # Don't waste time looping through everything...
     done
     if [ $exist -ne 0 ]; then
         tar czf "$fn" *"$dt"*
     fi
fi
```

(Your sample is an extra inside a loop with some copy-paste errors...)